# Can iSQL*Plus commands access the database ?

Tags: sql, isql

Can iSQL*Plus commands access the database ?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it can, that is its purpose. From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/html/A88826_01/ch12.htm):

> You can use iSQL*Plus to write SQL*Plus, SQL and PL/SQL commands to:
>
> - Enter, edit, run and save SQL commands and PL/SQL blocks.
> - Calculate, and print query results.
> - List column definitions for any table.
> - Access and copy data between databases.
> - Perform database administration.